# Submit form with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script to autosubmit on an intranet app. The problem I'm having is that the form uses multiple submit buttons, each with a unique name and value. A simple `form.submit()` won't work, so I'm lost. Below is an example.

How would I submit with the `Submit2` button, for example?

```
<form id='form1' action='action.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='whatever' />
    <input type='submit' name='Submit1' value='Submit1' />
    <input type='submit' name='Submit2' value='Submit2' />
    <input type='submit' name='Submit3' value='Submit3' />
</form>
```

Comment: What is `onclick` (or similar) defined as for the button in question?

Comment: There are no events handlers defined within the input tag. Would they be somewhere else?

Comment: They could well be anywhere in the JS. Since these are of the type `button`, and not `submit`, the form isn't being "submitted" per se; some other function is being called.

Comment: Oops...yes, they are type 'submit'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
document.getElementsByName('Submit2')[0].click();
```

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wmVdL/) on JSFiddle.

Comment: Great, thanks. I don't have VPN access now so I'll try tomorrow at work.

Comment: Consider also `document.getElementById('form1').Submit2.click()`.